# Substituting user-defined matrices into PETSc matrices

Tags: c++, mpi, sparse-matrix, petsc

I have sequential block AIJ matrices which are written in c++ and I am going to use PETSc to create MPI matrices. So, I have to substitute my sparse block AIJ matrices into MPI block AIJ PETSc matrices. Does anyone have any example on how to do that?
I would appreciate any suggestions regarding to the task I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good starting point may be http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/mat/examples/tutorials/ex5.c.html :

```
Opens a separate file for each process and reads in ITS portion
of a large parallel matrix. Only requires enough memory to store
the processes portion of the matrix ONCE.
```

It makes use of `MatSetValues()` to set values. Carefully read  the documentation to understand what you should do :  http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatSetValues.html . The chapter of PETSC'manual on Mat will also help you.

If you would like to work with blocked matrix (BAIJ), you may use `MatSetValuesBlocked()` http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatSetValuesBlocked.html#MatSetValuesBlocked
(and `MatSetBlockSize()`)

Bye,

Comment: Thank you Francis for your response. Do you have any example yourself?

Comment: You're welcome ! Sorry, i don't have such a clear and concise example. I thought `ex5.c` could be adapted to fit your need !